# How to superimpose a photo on the Friggeri CV template?

Tags: xetex, friggeri-cv

I am using the Friggeri CV template and was wondering how I can superimpose a passport-sized photo on the right side of the default black header.

If this has already been answered, please comment below with the link. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more details?  Do you want to place a photo overlapping the header, under the header, in place of the header, etc.?

Comment: Hi @Daniel, thanks for prompting. Specifically I want to superimpose a passport-sized photo on the right side of the black header.

Comment: If you just want to overlay a picture on top of things, you can just use the tikz package with the overlay option.  I had a quick search and didn't see any readily similar questions so I've posted an answer below.

Comment: @raimibkarim There's no need to add “[answered]” to the title; the fact that an answer has been given and accepted is already clear in the list of questions in the main page, so I rolled back. Don't worry and welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `tikz` [package](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) and create a `tikzpicture` environment with the `overlay` option.  You'll have to reference external nodes such as current page positions so you need the `remember picture` option as well, which allows you to reference nodes external to the environment.  I've included a simple MWE below (include the tikzpicture environment after you've created the header).  Note that you'll need to compile a couple of times for the image to show up.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{picture.png}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you want to be able to adjust the position away from the extreme top right of the page, you can load the tikz library `calc` which allows you to save and recall x and y node coordinates (See [this question's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18389/tikz-node-at-same-x-coordinate-as-another-node-but-specified-y-coordinate)).  In the MWE below, you can adjust the relative x and y position away from the top right by modifying the relevant subtracted values at the end of the `\path` line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \path let \p1 = (current page.north east) in node[anchor=north east] at (\x1-0cm,\y1-0cm) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{screenshot.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I tested the above in the Friggeri resume template and they appeared to work correctly.

Comment: thank you so much because that really helped and solved it!